# Regex - match every possible char and space

Tags: regex

I want to extract data from html. The thing is, that i cant extract 2 of strings which are on the top, and on the bottom of my pattern.

I want to extract `23423423423` and `1234523453245` but only, if there is string `Allan` between:

```
                                        <h4><a href="/Profile/23423423423.html">@@@@@@</a>  </h4> said12:49:32
            </div>

                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="replyAnswer(@@@@@@@@@@,'GET','');" class="reportLink">
                    report                    </a>
                        </div>

        <div class="details">
                            <p class="content">


                       Hi there, Allan.



                                </p>

            <div id="AddAnswer1234523453245"></div>
```

Of course, i can do something like this: `Profile\/(\d+).*\s*.*\s*.*\s*.*\s*.*\s*.*\s*.*\s*.*Allan.*\s*.*\s*.*AddAnswer(\d+)`. But the code is horrible. Is there any solution to make it shorter?

I was thinking about:

`Profile\/(\d+)(.\sAllan)*AddAnswer(\d+)`

or

`Profile\/(\d+)(.*Allan\s*)*AddAnswer(\d+)`

but none of wchich works properly. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: Im using iMacros. But it is the same (I think) as Regex101.com

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a character group to match any character including newlines by using `[\S\s]`. All space and non-space characters is all characters.

Then, your attempts were reasonably close

```
/Profile\/(\d+)[\S\s]*Allan[\S\s]*AddAnswer(\d+)/
```

This looks for the profile, the number that comes after it, any characters before Allan, any characters before AddAnswer, and the number that comes after it. If you have single-line mode available (`/s`) then you can use dots instead.

```
/Profile\/(\d+).*Allan.*AddAnswer(\d+)/s
```

<kbd>[demo](https://regex101.com/r/xQ9pM0/1)</kbd>

Comment: This won't work for multiple instances (it will only capture the last), see my answer for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `m` to specify `.` to match newlines.

`/Profile\/(\d+).+AddAnswer(\d+)/m`

Comment: Come on, this is utterly wrong - `s` is for single line mode, `m` is for multiline to match `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 0):

[Better use a parser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). If you must use regular expressions for whatever reason, you might get along with a [**tempered greedy solution**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
Profile/(\d+)            # Profile followed by digits
(?:(?!Allan)[\S\s])+     # any character except when there's Allan ahead
Allan                    # Allan literally
(?:(?!AddAnswer)[\S\s])+ # same construct as above
AddAnswer(\d+)           # AddAnswer, followed by digits
```

See a <kbd>[demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qH2gU3/1)</kbd>

Comment: I believe that regex with non-greedy matches like this might perform better:
`/Profile\/(\d+)[\s\S]*?Allan[\s\S]*?(\d+)/g`

Regex101 shows that 9110 steps are needed with your match pattern, while only 2740 steps are needed with this non-greedy one.